# Create Task Scheduler adding wake computer condition using batch script

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, sleep, scheduled-tasks

I have a batch script to create a task scheduler but I want to add the condition to WAKE THIS COMPUTER TO RUN THIS TASK. The purpose of this task is the wake the computer from sleep mode. I have already searched a lot articles in web but I cannot find any resolution regarding this function. Can any talented guys help me to get this done.
The code is just a simple code as follows :

```
schtasks /create /sc weekly /d mon,tue,wed,thu,fri /tn "Wake_Auto" /tr "%userprofile%\documents\sleeptowake\PC_Wake.cmd" /st 09:00
```

And the PC_Wake cmd is as follows :

```
Echo Hello!
ping 127.0.0.1
exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCHTASKS.exe is limited to commands with less than 255 characters and does not have access to all of Scheduler 2.0 options such as "Wake up the machine to run this task".

Source: https://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html

Comment: Thank you so much.